# Anypoint Studio 7.7.0 fails with fatal Windows application error on startup

Tags: mule-studio

I've recently starting looking at Anypoint Platform and Anypoint Studio.  I'm on Windows 10 (17763).

I installed the currently latest version of Anypoint Studio, version 7.7.0.  Just about every other time I start it, after a minute or so after starting it up, I get a dialog like the following:

[image: JVM error dialog]

When I dismiss it, obviously the application goes away.

I've inspected the Eclipse error log, and nothing appears associated with this.  However, the Windows event log does show something, but it's not much more than nothing.

I only see the following in the event:

```
Faulting application name: javaw.exe, version: 8.0.2650.1, time stamp: 0x5f204288
Faulting module name: QIPCAP64.dll, version: 7.6.818.1, time stamp: 0x5f45806b
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0000000000030fdf
Faulting process id: 0x7f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6c2b1c1e4c539
Faulting application path: C:\AnypointStudio-7.7.0-win64\AnypointStudio\plugins\org.mule.tooling.jdk.win32.x86_64_1.0.1\bin\javaw.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\QIPCAP64.dll
Report Id: 55e2303f-ba56-4715-ac7e-71aedcf86474
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

This has been very consistent.  I have rebooted many times, and that has no effect.

What DID have sort of an impact was installing the previous version, 7.6.0.  I've tested them both many times now, and I never see this error from 7.6.0.

The "Anypoint.ini" file is almost unchanged, although I did increase the "Xmx" value to 2048m.  I have also tried changing this to use the Java 8 distribution that I had installed before this.  The only thing that changes when I do that is to change the error dialog slightly, indicating that it's coming from the other Java distribution, not the one included with Studio, along with the Windows event log entry showing the path to the expected Java distribution.

It's not clear to me whether the reference to the "QIPCAP64" dll is relevant.

I did report this to Mulesoft, but I'm not very hopeful they're going to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QIPCAP64.dll seems to be part of forcepoint.com security products. Looks like it doesn't like Studio 7.7.

Comment: I finally got an update to my Forcepoint installation this morning, and I no longer get the error.